# Android Maps Utils Clustering show InfoWindow

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I am planning to use the google maps marker clustering available in the utils library, but the google example app only shows marker clusters without any infoWindow. I am wondering now, am I not able to show a InfoWindow? I want the InfoWindow to be displayed on the marker like with a normal google maps marker, not on the cluster.

The code I have: (From the google example)

```
public class BigClusteringDemoActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private ClusterManager<MyItem> mClusterManager;
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private void readItems() {
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.radar_search);
        List<MyItem> items = new MyItemReader().read(inputStream);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            double offset = i / 60d;
            for (MyItem item : items) {
                LatLng position = item.getPosition();
                double lat = position.latitude + offset;
                double lng = position.longitude + offset;
                MyItem offsetItem = new MyItem(lat, lng);
                mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(this, mMap);

        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(51.503186, -0.126446), 10));
        mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);

        readItems();
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968486/how-to-add-info-window-for-clustering-marker-in-android

Comment: @DanielNugent as far as I understood, the link u gave me explained how to add an InfoWindow to the entire cluster. I want to display a normal InfoWindow on a single marker when clicked on it, like the normal google map does it

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here is a simplified and slightly modified solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968486/how-to-add-info-window-for-clustering-marker-in-android/25969059#25969059).  Note that the linked answer implements an InfoWindow for both Markers and Clusters.

This solution only implements InfoWindows for Markers.

It's similar to how you would implement a custom InfoWindowAdapter for normal Markers with no Clustering, but with the additional requirement that you keep a reference to the currently selected Item so that you can get the Title and Snippet from it's `MyItem` instance, since the Marker does not store the Title and Snippet as it usually does.

Note that since all of the data is stored in `MyItem` references, it's much easier to extend the functionality to display as many data types as you want in the InfoWindow for each Marker.

First, the MyItem.java, which includes extra fields for Title and Snippet:

```
public class MyItem implements ClusterItem {
    private final LatLng mPosition;
    private final String mTitle;
    private final String mSnippet;

    public MyItem(double lat, double lng, String t, String s) {
        mPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        mTitle = t;
        mSnippet = s;
    }

    @Override
    public LatLng getPosition() {
        return mPosition;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return mTitle;
    }

    public String getSnippet(){
        return mSnippet;
    }
}
```

Here is the full Activity class, which includes all of the functionality to support InfoWindows for each Marker added using the Cluster library:

Edit:  Added support for handling click events on the InfoWindow, made the Activity implement `OnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener` and added the `onClusterItemInfoWindowClick` callback.

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements ClusterManager.OnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener<MyItem> {

    private ClusterManager<MyItem> mClusterManager;
    private MyItem clickedClusterItem;
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }


    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();

            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }

        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {

        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(this, mMap);

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(37.779977,-122.413742), 10));

        mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(mClusterManager.getMarkerManager());

        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(mClusterManager); //added
        mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener(this); //added

        mClusterManager
                .setOnClusterItemClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<MyItem>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onClusterItemClick(MyItem item) {
                        clickedClusterItem = item;
                        return false;
                    }
                });



        addItems();

        mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().setOnInfoWindowAdapter(
                new MyCustomAdapterForItems());

    }

    private void addItems() {

        double latitude = 37.779977;
        double longitude = -122.413742;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            double offset = i / 60d;

            double lat = latitude + offset;
            double lng = longitude + offset;
            MyItem offsetItem = new MyItem(lat, lng, "title " + i+1, "snippet " + i+1);
            mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);

        }

    }

    //added with edit
    @Override
    public void onClusterItemInfoWindowClick(MyItem myItem) {

        //Cluster item InfoWindow clicked, set title as action
        Intent i = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
        i.setAction(myItem.getTitle());
        startActivity(i);

        //You may want to do different things for each InfoWindow:
        if (myItem.getTitle().equals("some title")){

            //do something specific to this InfoWindow....

        }

    }

    public class MyCustomAdapterForItems implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

        private final View myContentsView;

        MyCustomAdapterForItems() {
            myContentsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.info_window, null);
        }
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

            TextView tvTitle = ((TextView) myContentsView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtTitle));
            TextView tvSnippet = ((TextView) myContentsView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtSnippet));

            tvTitle.setText(clickedClusterItem.getTitle());
            tvSnippet.setText(clickedClusterItem.getSnippet());

            return myContentsView;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

info_window.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:textColor="#D3649F"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSnippet"
        android:textColor="#D3649F"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Result:

Initial launch:

[image]

Zooming out, starts Clustering:

[image]

Zooming out again, more Clustering:

[image]

Then, zooming in, and clicking on an individual Marker:

[image]

Then clicking on another Marker:

[image]

Edit:  In order to show the "speech bubble" around the custom InfoWindow, use `getInfoContents()` instead of `getInfoWindow()`:

```
public class MyCustomAdapterForItems implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    private final View myContentsView;

    MyCustomAdapterForItems() {
        myContentsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.info_window, null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

        TextView tvTitle = ((TextView) myContentsView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtTitle));
        TextView tvSnippet = ((TextView) myContentsView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtSnippet));

        tvTitle.setText(clickedClusterItem.getTitle());
        tvSnippet.setText(clickedClusterItem.getSnippet());

        return myContentsView;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent answer! :) How would I add the little down arrow below the InfoWindow like the normal InfoWindow has? Also how would I add an onInfoWindowClickListener? The same way I would do it with a normal map?

Comment: @qwertz I will have to look into that! For the info window click, I'll get it working and update the answer!

Comment: @qwertz I just got the InfoWindow click handling working, and added the updated code to the answer.  Take a look at the lines of code with the `added` comment, and also the class definition and the new override method `onClusterItemInfoWindowClick()`.

Comment: thank you very much! Is it possible to add the speechbubble arrow to the bottom of the infowindow?

Comment: @qwertz I still need to look into that, I'll be sure to update you if I find anything!  I'm not sure why it's not there, I'll need to do some research.

Comment: What does the OtherActivity class referenced in onClusterItemInfoWindowClick relate too?

Comment: @Mike OtherActivity is the Activity that would open when the InfoWindow is clicked.  This is just an example of one common thing you could do when an InfoWindow is clicked.

Comment: Thanks Daniel :) I was misreading it before as to what the event handler was doing. Makes a lot more sense now!

Comment: Thanks! How should one do this if he has two ClusterManagers. The problem occurs when you do GoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(ClusterManager.getMarkerManager())
Only the last manger will work but not the previous. There isn't such a thing as MultiAdapter (like MultiListener)

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(this, mMap);

        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(51.503186, -0.126446), 10));
        mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {
        /**
         * View for displaying marker popup, if null default framework view would be used
         */
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * For changing the content of infowindow
         * Called when showMarkerInfo method is called
         */
        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_to_inflate, null);      
            //code for initializing view part
            return v;
        }
    });
        readItems();
    }
```

Comment: Would I have to add a title and snippet field in the MyItem class? How do I add a title and snippet to the marker?

Comment: I think, you have to add title and snippet

Answer (score 0):

You could consider the following approach:

```
public void initilizeMap() {
            googleMap = mFragment.getMap();
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true`enter code here`); // true to`enter code here`
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sorry! unable to create maps",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(getActivity(),   googleMap );
//          googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter());
            googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this);
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setTiltGesturesEnabled(true);

MyItem offsetItem = new MyItem(Double.parseDouble(outletList.get(i).getMap_latitude()),
                                           Double.parseDouble(outletList.get(i).getMap_longitude()), title , address);
            mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
            googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(offsetItem));

}


    private class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {
        Marker marker;
        private View view;
        private MyItem items;

        public CustomInfoWindowAdapter(MyItem item) {
            view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
            this.items = item;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            if (marker != null && marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
                marker.hideInfoWindow();
                marker.showInfoWindow();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) {
            this.marker = marker;

            String url = null;

            if (marker.getId() != null && markers != null && markers.size() > 0) {
                if (markers.get(marker.getId()) != null
                        && markers.get(marker.getId()) != null) {
                    url = markers.get(marker.getId());
                }
            }

            final ImageView image = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge));

            if (url != null && !url.equalsIgnoreCase("null")
                    && !url.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                imageLoader.displayImage(url, image, options,
                        new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,
                                    View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                                super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view,
                                        loadedImage);
                                getInfoContents(marker);
                            }
                        });
            } else {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }

            final String title = items.getTitle();
            Log.e(TAG, "TITLE : "+title);
            final TextView titleUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title));
            if (title != null) {
                titleUi.setText(title);
            } else {
                titleUi.setText("");
            }

            final String address = items.getAddress();
            final TextView snippetUi = ((TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.snippet));
            if (address != null) {
                snippetUi.setText(address);
            } else {
                snippetUi.setText("");
            }
```