# How can I use functions like onClusterItemRendered for my ClusterManager?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, markerclusterer

I am trying to get a reference to my markers (without using `getMarkerCollections`) on my clustered Google Map 
but I am having trouble finding where to override this function.

I have made a typical `ClusterManager` that works fine, 
but I can't override the function anywhere in that class.

Do I need to make a custom class for this and how would I do that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Take a look at this answer just in case it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958224/android-maps-utils-clustering-show-infowindow/30959578#30959578

Comment: @DanielNugent thanks for the quick answer, but I am trying to get a reference to all the markers on my map and then put them in a list.  You commented on my other question, but I think this is the better question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly, you will need to create a custom class that extends DefaultClusterRenderer, and then override the `onClusterItemRendered()` method:

```
public class MyRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MyItem> {

    public MyRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap map, ClusterManager<MyItem> clusterManager) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClusterItemRendered(MyItem clusterItem,
                                         Marker marker) {
        super.onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem, marker);

        //other stuff......
    }
}
```

Then, you would call the `setRenderer()` method and give it a new instance of your MyRenderer object:

```
mClusterManager.setRenderer(new MyRenderer(this, mMap, mClusterManager));
```

Comment: I just have a quick relevant question that I wanted to ask you: is there any way to get a reference to a clustered marker (as in a marker that is clustered, not the cluster circle itself)?

Comment: @jacob it's probably not necessary to do that.  Can you explain exactly what functionally you need that is not included in the answer I linked to? I can help guide you in the right direction.