# How to set info window details in Google Maps Clustering Utility Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am trying to display a list of venues on Google Maps in Android, which can be clustered on zoom out and on zoom in unclustered.

WHEN UNCLUSTERED, an individual item info window can be opened to look at that venue details, and clicked to open a separate activity.

I am using this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering?hl=en

I am doing this :

Getting Map Fragment in onResume()

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Getting map for the map fragment
    mapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(new VenuesInLocationOnMapReadyCallback(getContext()));

    // Adding map fragment to the view using fragment transaction
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.venues_in_location_support_map_fragment_container, mapFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

MapReadyCallback :

```
private class VenuesInLocationOnMapReadyCallback implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private static final float ZOOM_LEVEL = 10;
    private final Context context;

    public VenuesInLocationOnMapReadyCallback(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap map) {
        // Setting up marker clusters
        setUpClusterManager(getContext(), map);

        // Allowing user to select My Location
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // My location button handler to check the location setting enable
        map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
                promptForLocationSetting(getContext(), map);
                // Returning false ensures camera try to move to user location
                return false;
            }
        });

        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        // Disabling map toolbar
        map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Setting up Cluster Manager

```
private void setUpClusterManager(final Context context, GoogleMap map) {
    // Declare a variable for the cluster manager.
    ClusterManager<LocationMarker> mClusterManager;

    // Position the map.
    LatLng wocLatLng = new LatLng(28.467948, 77.080685);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(wocLatLng, VenuesInLocationOnMapReadyCallback.ZOOM_LEVEL));

    // Initialize the manager with the context and the map.
    mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<LocationMarker>(context, map);

    // Point the map's listeners at the listeners implemented by the cluster
    // manager.
    map.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

    // Add cluster items (markers) to the cluster manager.
    addLocations(mClusterManager);

    // Setting custom cluster marker manager for info window adapter
    map.setInfoWindowAdapter(mClusterManager.getMarkerManager());
    mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().setOnInfoWindowAdapter(new MyLocationInfoWindowAdapter());

    map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new MyMarkerInfoWindowClickListener());
}
```

Adding Cluster items (markers)

```
private void addLocations(ClusterManager<LocationMarker> mClusterManager) {

    for (int i = 0; i < venuesDetailsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject thisVenueJson = (JSONObject) venuesDetailsJsonArray.get(i);
            JSONObject thisVenueLocationJson = thisVenueJson.getJSONObject("location");
            LocationMarker thisVenueMarker = new LocationMarker(thisVenueLocationJson.getDouble("latitude"),
                    thisVenueLocationJson.getDouble("longitude"), thisVenueJson.getInt("id"));
            mClusterManager.addItem(thisVenueMarker);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

MyLocationInfoWIndowAdapter

```
private class MyLocationInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        Log.e("getInfoContent", marker.toString());
        View venueInfoWindow = ((LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                .inflate(R.layout.venues_map_item, null);
        return venueInfoWindow;
    }
}
```

MarkerInfoWindowClickListener

```
private class MyMarkerInfoWindowClickListener implements GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        // TODO: This is the click listener, that means all the info must be added as Tag to Marker
        Intent venueDetailsDisplayIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), VenueDetailsDisplayActivity.class);
        startActivity(venueDetailsDisplayIntent);
    }
}
```

Location Marker class

```
public class LocationMarker implements ClusterItem{
private final LatLng mPosition;
private final int id;

public LocationMarker(double lat, double lng, int id) {
    mPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public LatLng getPosition() {
    return mPosition;
}

public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```

}

The way that I am understanding the flow is this :

onResume --> fragmentTransaction --> VenuesInLocationOnMapReadyCallback --> setUpClusterManager --> addLocations (This adds Custom markers)

Marker Click --> MyLocationInfoWindowAdapter --> getInfoContents(Marker marker)

Marker Info Window click --> MyMarkerInfoWindowClickListener

According to my Understanding of process (I could be wrong):

I am adding an id to my custom LocationMarker when Adding markers in addLocations function.

I need to display different info in infoWindow for different markers.

InfoWindow is displayed using MyLocationInfoWindowAdapter-->getInfoContents(Marker marker)

But here is the rub, I can't find a way to figure out which marker has been clicked upon so that I can set appropriate info in InfoWindow.

On Click on opened InfoWindow I need to open a separate Activity. A/C to me InfoWindow click is handled using MyMarkerInfoWindowClickListener-->onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker)  Here too I am having the same problem (I can't figure out which marker's info window has been clicked).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Maps Utils Clustering show InfoWindow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958224/android-maps-utils-clustering-show-infowindow)

Comment: For the first issue, see `clickedClusterItem` in the linked answer.  For the second issue, Instead of `implements GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener` use `implements ClusterManager.OnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener<MyItem>`, and then implement the `onClusterItemInfoWindowClick()` method.  See answer in linked question for more specific details.