# Is there a way to show info of all clusterItems (without click)?

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow, markerclusterer

I am following [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958224/android-maps-utils-clustering-show-infowindow) to show info window on click. but i want to show info of all cluster items without clicking on it. is it possible with info windows? if not what is the ideal way to show info of all cluster items on map

Answer (score 1):

Well, what official doc says about [Maps - Info Windows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows#introduction) is

> An info window allows you to display information to the user when they tap on a marker. **Only one info window is displayed at a time**. If a user clicks on another marker, the current info window will be hidden and the new info window will be displayed.

Other way around will be, display your Info Windows as Marker. However this will not be a good solution if your Info Window design/view contains many views(childs).